# TSQL Flatten Split Tab Delimited Column

Tags: csv, t-sql, tabs, delimiter, sql-server-2019

I am importing error log flat files into my SQL server, and need to parse a tab-delimited column into multiple columns.  Borrowing heavily from this question ([SQL Split Tab Delimited Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259236/sql-split-tab-delimited-column)), specifically the answer from @Lobo, I want to accomplish a couple of things:

- capture the maximum amount of columns created using STRING_SPLIT() on
  [Column 0], so that I can create dynamic PIVOTs, in the eventuality
  that there are more columns than what I am currently aware of
- properly combine the parsed [Column 0] columns with the rest of the
  record

The first goal (dynamic column count) I can live without for the time being, but it's the second goal I am having issues with.

```
DECLARE @SAMPLE_TABLE table(
    [Column 0] nvarchar(4000),
    [Filename] nvarchar(260),
    FileExtention varchar(255),
    DateTimeStamp datetime,
    CustomerNumber varchar(255),
    FileType varchar(255),
    ImportSetNumber varchar(255)
)
```

Some sample data for the table:

```
[Column 0]                                                                                                                                | [Filename]                                                       | FileExtention | DateTimeStamp           | CustomerNumber | FileType | ImportSetNumber
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1<tab>Import Set No (A): 03300001: Contact ID (G): Invalid contact ID for this customer and company....Taker (I): Invalid taker.<tab><tab>| E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001
1<tab>Import Set No (A): 03300001: General Error: This Record and its related Records failed validation.<tab>0<tab>218                    | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001
1<tab>Import Set No (A): 04040186: General Error: This Record and its related Records failed validation.<tab>0<tab>17                     | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_18120_20230404084926_04040186.err | err           | 2023-04-04 08:49:26.000 | 18120          | OHF      | 04040186
```

Let the games begin

```
;WITH
CTE_Columns AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 'MyRowID',
            [Filename],
            FileExtention,
            DateTimeStamp,
            CustomerNumber,
            FileType,
            ImportSetNumber,
            A.ColID 'ColumnNumber',
            A.Cols 'ColumnValue'
    FROM @SAMPLE_TABLE
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ColID,
                value [Cols]
                FROM STRING_SPLIT([Column 0], CHAR(9))  -- split by tab character
    )A
)

SELECT MyRowID,
        [Filename],
        FileExtention,
        DateTimeStamp,
        CustomerNumber,
        FileType,
        ImportSetNumber,
        NULLIF(TRIM([1]), '') 'FirstColumn',
        NULLIF(TRIM([2]), '') 'SecondColumn',
        NULLIF(TRIM([3]), '') 'ThirdColumn',
        NULLIF(TRIM([4]), '') 'FourthColumn'
FROM (
        SELECT MyRowID,
                [Filename],
                FileExtention,
                DateTimeStamp,
                CustomerNumber,
                FileType,
                ImportSetNumber,
                ColumnNumber,
                ColumnValue
        FROM CTE_Columns
)Q
PIVOT(MAX(Q.ColumnValue) FOR ColumnNumber IN([1], [2], [3], [4])) PIV
ORDER BY CustomerNumber,
            ImportSetNumber
```

This query produces the following resultset:

```
MyRowID | Filename                                                         | FileExtention | DateTimeStamp           | CustomerNumber | FileType | ImportSetNumber | FirstColumn | SecondColumn                                                                                                               | ThirdColumn | FourthColumn
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | 1           | NULL                                                                                                                       | NULL        | NULL
2       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | NULL        | Import Set No (A): 03300001: Contact ID (G): Invalid contact ID for this customer and company....Taker (I): Invalid taker. | NULL        | NULL
3       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | NULL        | NULL                                                                                                                       | NULL        | NULL
4       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | NULL        | NULL                                                                                                                       | NULL        | NULL
5       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | 1           | NULL                                                                                                                       | NULL        | NULL
6       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | NULL        | Import Set No (A): 03300001: General Error: This Record and its related Records failed validation.                         | NULL        | NULL
7       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | NULL        | NULL                                                                                                                       | 0           | NULL
8       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | NULL        | NULL                                                                                                                       | NULL        | 218
9       | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_18120_20230404084926_04040186.err | err           | 2023-04-04 08:49:26.000 | 18120          | OHF      | 04040186        | 1           | NULL                                                                                                                       | NULL        | NULL
10      | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_18120_20230404084926_04040186.err | err           | 2023-04-04 08:49:26.000 | 18120          | OHF      | 04040186        | NULL        | Import Set No (A): 04040186: General Error: This Record and its related Records failed validation.                         | NULL        | NULL
11      | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_18120_20230404084926_04040186.err | err           | 2023-04-04 08:49:26.000 | 18120          | OHF      | 04040186        | NULL        | NULL                                                                                                                       | 0           | NULL
12      | E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_18120_20230404084926_04040186.err | err           | 2023-04-04 08:49:26.000 | 18120          | OHF      | 04040186        | NULL        | NULL                                                                                                                       | NULL        | 17
```

Based on the resultset above, rows 1- 4 should be one record, rows 5 - 8 should be a second record, and rows 9 - 12 should be a third record, giving me my desired end-state of:

```
Filename                                                         | FileExtention | DateTimeStamp           | CustomerNumber | FileType | ImportSetNumber | FirstColumn | SecondColumn                                                                                                               | ThirdColumn | FourthColumn
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | 1           | Import Set No (A): 03300001: Contact ID (G): Invalid contact ID for this customer and company....Taker (I): Invalid taker. | NULL        | NULL
E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_10047_20230330113636_03300001.err | err           | 2023-03-30 11:36:36.000 | 10047          | OHF      | 03300001        | 1           | Import Set No (A): 03300001: General Error: This Record and its related Records failed validation.                         | 0           | 218
E:\path\to\files\Errors\SO_OHF_18120_20230404084926_04040186.err | err           | 2023-04-04 08:49:26.000 | 18120          | OHF      | 04040186        | 1           | Import Set No (A): 04040186: General Error: This Record and its related Records failed validation.                         | 0           | 17
```

I believe this would just be a simple matter of correct grouping, but I'm not sure what to group on, or where to properly put the grouping (whether it would be a partitioning or a standard GROUP BY clause somewhere)

Comment: Why dont't you just use a proper bulk import system, such as `bcp.exe` or `BULK INSERT` or `SqlBulkCopy` rather than rolling your own?

Comment: check SQL Server LEAD() function. it might help to read next offecet lines, than will select first rows.

Comment: in addition, 
and this link would be valuable for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783680/sql-pivot-and-string-concatenation-aggregate

Answer (score 0):

You need to regroup the rows in a correct way and combine the parsed columns by adding a new column which can act as a grouping identifier :

```sql
;WITH CTE_Columns AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS MyRowID,
        [Filename],
        FileExtention,
        DateTimeStamp,
        CustomerNumber,
        FileType,
        ImportSetNumber,
        A.ColID AS ColumnNumber,
        A.Cols AS ColumnValue
    FROM @SAMPLE_TABLE
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ColID,
            value AS Cols
            FROM STRING_SPLIT([Column 0], CHAR(9)) -- split by tab character
    ) A
), CTE_Grouping AS (
    SELECT MyRowID,
        [Filename],
        FileExtention,
        DateTimeStamp,
        CustomerNumber,
        FileType,
        ImportSetNumber,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNumber = 1 THEN ColumnValue END) AS FirstColumn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNumber = 2 THEN ColumnValue END) AS SecondColumn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNumber = 3 THEN ColumnValue END) AS ThirdColumn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNumber = 4 THEN ColumnValue END) AS FourthColumn
    FROM CTE_Columns
    GROUP BY MyRowID, [Filename], FileExtention, DateTimeStamp, CustomerNumber, FileType, ImportSetNumber
)
SELECT [Filename],
    FileExtention,
    DateTimeStamp,
    CustomerNumber,
    FileType,
    ImportSetNumber,
    FirstColumn,
    SecondColumn,
    ThirdColumn,
    FourthColumn
FROM CTE_Grouping
ORDER BY CustomerNumber, ImportSetNumber
```

Inside the `CTE_Grouping`, the `MAX` function is used with conditional statement to combine the parsed columns `ColumnValue` based on their corresponding column numbers `ColumnNumber`. This will ensure that each grouping has only one row with the combined values.

The outer query selects the desired columns from the `CTE_Grouping` and orders the result by `CustomerNumber` and `ImportSetNumber`.